# Operations in class diagrams

Tags: class, uml, diagram, operation

my question is in relation to operations on a class diagram.

I'm very new to UML and I am creating a class diagram for an online quiz system where a teacher will assign login details to a student, the teacher will create a multiple choice quiz and then from a specified time, students can log in to complete the quiz.

My question is in relation to the operations included. For example, the teacher will add a 'QuizQuestion'. So can I include the operation 'addQuizQuestion()' in the 'Teacher' class as the 'Teacher' will perform the task or shall I add it to the 'QuizQuestion' class as it is what is being created?

Similary, once results have been collated, reports are generated and sent out to parents. So shall I have a 'receiveReport()' operation in the 'Parent' class or should there be a 'sendReport()' operation in the 'Report' class?

I'm so confused!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion has nothing to do with diagramming and everything to do with basic object oriented concepts such as in your particular case, roles and responsibilities. I think you would do yourself (and your teacher) a favor by reading a book on this topic such as [Object Design: Roles, Responsibilities, and Collaborations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379430) or a more general OO book such as [The Object-Oriented Thought Process](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321861272), before embarking on this project.